# Is is OK to use a non-zero return code for a process that executed successfully?

Tags: linux, process

I'm implementing a simple job scheduler, which spans a new process for every job to run. When a job exits, I'd like it to report the number of actions executed to the scheduler.

The simplest way I could find, is to exit with the number of actions as a return code. The process would for example exit with return code `3` for "3 actions executed".

But the standard (AFAIK) being to use the return code `0` when a process exited successfully, and any other value when there was en error, would this approach risk to create any problem?

---

Note: the child process is not an executable script, but a fork of the parent, so not accessible from the outside world.

Comment: Typically a positive return code indicates success but with something that didn't go *quite* right, -ve return codes are errors.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is inter process communication  - and there are plenty ways to do it:

- Sockets
- Shared memory
- Pipes
- Exclusive file descriptors (to some extend, rather go for something else if you can)
- ...

Return convention changes are not something a regular programmer should dare to violate.

Comment: To be honest, I _would_ dare doing that, in this particular case. Other solutions are certainly "cleaner" but the OP was interested in a simple solution (returning a number from `main` _is simple_) and given that the forking process knows that the usual convention isn't respected (and doesn't care, because all it cares for is that number), this is an acceptable solution, in my opinion.

Comment: @Damon Forking might be an exception and if one only needs that one single number for a quick hack it indeed is fine. But usually, you need more than one number from your forked/other processes (and be it only for statistics collection, debugging). The cleaner way would be to use ipc from the very beginning, usually saves some redesign later on (that is what my experience says, but yours might differ and I am probably not as experienced as you are so...).

Answer (score 1):

The only risk is confusing a calling script.  What you describe makes sense, since what you want really is the count.  As Joe said, use negative values for failures, and you should consider including a --help option that explains the return values ... so you can figure out what this code is doing when you try to use it next month.

Comment: Actually this is a process forked from the parent, so there cannot be such thing as a calling script!

Comment: I this case, it's perfectly "OK". It is not "the standard" under Unix, but who cares. It's not illegal.

Comment: Benjamin - You should not forget that it is quite possible you will realize in the not-too-distant future just how useful this script is and find yourself calling it from many other scripts.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use logs for it: log the number of actions executed to the scheduler. This way you can also log datetimes and other extra info.

I would not change the return convention...

Answer (score 0):

If the scheduler spans a child and you are writing that you could also open a pipe per child, or a named pipes or maybe unix domain sockets, and use that for inter process communication and writing the processed jobs there.

I would stick with conventions, namely returning 0 for success, expecially if your program is visible/usable around by other people, or anyway document well those decisions.

Anyway apart from conventions there are also [standards](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html).

Comment: Does the fact that this is a process forked from the parent (not an executable script) change anything?

Comment: no it doesn't, I was in fact referring to child-parent processes there, and in some cases you are also facilitated from the fact that when you fork your file descriptors are *inherited* (man fork for more info) , you could also have external scripts that don't know much of each other if you want to use named pipes or external type communication.

Comment: uh maybe you meant if it changes something to have standards or not even if the process is internal. I think that standards are there for helping programmers to share knowledge and conventions, if someday I would pick up your code and if it **easy** for me to understand your conventions, you made the right decision, otherwise think twice about that :)